# How to run custom compare script on the original and modified file of a Merge Request

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a CI script for LabVIEW projects. I have a script that needs 2 arguments (old-file, new-file), and gives me a visual overview about the changes between the 2 files. The file names must be different!
I want to use this script in a Merge Request. For this I need a list of the modified files in the MR, and a way to feed the old-file,new-file pair into the script for all the files that are changed.

I have the following pipeline as start. The 'pseudo-code' part is where I need some help.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'

MassCompile:
  stage: MassCompile
  tags:
    - labview,linux
  script:
    - echo "Executing MassCompile stage"
    - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - echo $CI_BUILDS_DIR
    - xvfb-run -a LabVIEWCLI -LabVIEWPath "/usr/local/natinst/LabVIEW-2023-64/labview" -OperationName MassCompile -DirectoryToCompile $CI_PROJECT_DIR

Diff:
  stage: Diff
  tags:
    - labview,linux
  script:
    - echo "Executing Diff stage"
    - git fetch
    - git diff --name-only origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME | grep '\.vi$'
    - <pseudo-code>:
      -- for each file-in-the-list-above as changedFile
      {
        - old-file = get changedFile from the target branch
        - rename old-file: changedFile-old
        - call compare-script(changedFile, changedFile-old)
      }

stages:
  - MassCompile
  - Diff
```

So the 'pseudo-code' part should do the following:

- Get the original file of the target branch for each file that has been updated.
- Rename this file.
- Call the compare script with the renamed file and the one from the MR.

What would be the best possible way to achieve what I am looking for? Shall I checkout the target branch, and try to locate the relevant file in the checked out directory? How to do this? Is there maybe a git command that can give me the 'before' and 'after' version of each file in a MR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final pipeline script (thanks to ChatGPT!):

```
default:
  tags:
    - labview,linux

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'

MassCompile:
  stage: MassCompile
  script:
    - echo "Executing MassCompile stage"
    - xvfb-run -a LabVIEWCLI -LabVIEWPath "/usr/local/natinst/LabVIEW-2023-64/labview" -OperationName MassCompile -DirectoryToCompile $CI_PROJECT_DIR

Diff:
  stage: Diff
  script:
    - echo "Executing Diff stage"
    - git fetch
    - git worktree add -f __target-branch $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
    - |
      IFS=$'\n'
      for file in $(git diff --name-only origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME | grep '\.vi$'); do
        directory=$(dirname "$file")
        modified_file_path="$CI_PROJECT_DIR/$file"
        original_file_path=$(find "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/__target-branch" -type f -name "$(basename "$file")" -print -quit)
        if [ -z "$original_file_path" ]; then
          echo "Original file not found for: $modified_file_path"
          continue
        fi
        original_file_dir=$(dirname "$original_file_path")
        renamed_file_path="$original_file_dir/$(basename "$file")-orig"
        echo "Modified file: $modified_file_path"
        echo "Located in directory: $directory"
        echo "Original file: $original_file_path"
        echo "Renamed file: $renamed_file_path"
        # Rename the original file
        mv "$original_file_path" "$renamed_file_path"
        # Call your script with the modified and renamed file paths as arguments
        # ./your_script.sh "$modified_file_path" "$renamed_file_path"
      done

stages:
  - MassCompile
  - Diff
```